# How do I link bonita processes to my project service layer?

Tags: service, bonita

I am new to bonita and still trying to wrap my head around workflow management. I have this project in maven with a service layer in project architecture that does CRUD. Am exploring how the service layer can be called/call the process definition/instance/variable to access the database. Can anyone give me an insight?

Answer (score 1):

From Bonita to your service layer you can use:

- [Connectors](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/connectivity): they are associated with tasks when creating processes definitions and executed when a process instance reach the task.
- [Event handlers](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/event-handlers): they are associated with specific Bonita Engine events (such as creating a new process instance, initializing a step...). They can be use to trigger some code execution that should apply to several deployed processes.

From your service layer to Bonita you can use:

- Engine APIs using the Java client library
- REST API